# Pandas: Getting multiple columns based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame `df` like this:

```
Date           Student_id    Subject     Subject_Scores
11/30/2020     1000101       Math           70
11/25/2020     1000101       Physics        75
12/02/2020     1000101       Biology        60
11/25/2020     1000101       Chemistry      49
11/25/2020     1000101       English        80
12/02/2020     1000101       Biology        60
11/25/2020     1000101       Chemistry      49
11/25/2020     1000101       English        80
12/02/2020     1000101       Sociology      50
11/25/2020     1000102       Physics        80
11/25/2020     1000102       Math           90
12/15/2020     1000102       Chemistry      63
12/15/2020     1000103       English        71
```

**case:1**

If I use `df[df['Student_id]=='1000102']['Date']`, this gives unique dates for that particular `Student_id`.
How can I get the same for multiple columns with single condition.

I want to get multiple columns based on condition, how can I get output `df` something like this for Student_id = 1000102:

```
Date            Subject     
11/25/2020      Physics        
11/25/2020      Math           
12/15/2020      Chemistry
```

I have tried this, but getting error:

`df[df['Student_id']=='1000102']['Date', 'Subject']`
**And**

`df[df['Student_id']=='1000102']['Date']['Subject']`

**case:2**

How can I use df.unique() in the above scenario(for multiple columns)

`df[df['Student_id']=='1000102']['Date', 'Subject'].unique()  #this gives error`

How could this be possibly achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass list to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Student_id']=='1000102', ['Date', 'Subject']]
print (df1)
          Date    Subject
9   11/25/2020    Physics
10  11/25/2020       Math
11  12/15/2020  Chemistry
```

If need unique values add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Student_id']=='1000102', ['Date', 'Subject']].drop_duplicates()
print (df2)
          Date    Subject
9   11/25/2020    Physics
10  11/25/2020       Math
11  12/15/2020  Chemistry
```

If need [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) for each column separately:

```
df3 = df.loc[df['Student_id']=='1000102', ['Date', 'Subject']].apply(lambda x: x.unique())
print (df3)
Date         [11/25/2020, 12/15/2020]
Subject    [Physics, Math, Chemistry]
dtype: object
```